# .htaccess file causing Chrome to lose session data

Tags: php, session, google-chrome, mod-rewrite

I've got a problem where my session data is being lost in Google Chrome. All other browsers handle the sessions fine.

I've narrowed it down to the following line in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ customForest.php?slug=$1 [QSA]
```

If I remove this line, the sessions work fine in Google Chrome.

Does anyone have any idea what in this line might be causing the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's caused by the `[QSA]` flag. You might try this:

```
RewriteRule .* customForest.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Comment: This seems to break all of my paths.

Does the .* mean apply this to all files?

Comment: `http://mydomain.com/customForest.php...` is always the URL in my answer because from your question it was impossible to determine anything else. However, that's only an example of how to use QUERY_STRING to capture the query string instead of the pattern in your question with the `QSA` flag, which is repeating the parameter twice: `slug=parameter&slug=parameter`.

Comment: Actually it looks like the ^ at the start of the rewrite rule is what is causing the issue. Not the [QSA]. If I remove the ^ and specify a specific slug like this:

RewriteRule test/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ customForest.php?slug=$1 [QSA]

it works.

Comment: Of course. Without `^` there is only 1 instance of the query string and the same happens without [QSA], but I am not interested in a discussion to prove I am right. This is not the place to do it. The important thing is now you know what's originating the problem, that's all.